# Intersection of all rows of a single column in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, intersection

I have a dataframe that has a column containing list values as rows. I want to find intersection of all the rows of the column efficiently. Right now the code I have implemented iterates over the dataframe. Looking for a way without using the loop...
Given below is a sample df. I am trying to find intersection of tokens column

```
query                 tokens
ABC                   [A,B,C]
CDE                   [C,D,E]   
FGH                   [A,E,C]
```

My expected output is [C]

My df has more than 20k rows

Comment: please show an example

Comment: sure the question is updated

Comment: `df['query'].eq(df['tokens'].apply(','.join))`

Comment: @ansev After intersection, I thought the output would be a list. I tried your code and gives True or False for each row and not the list/set of the commonly found items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `numpy.intersect1d` and `functools.reduce`.

```
from functools import reduce
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

In [48]: df = pd.DataFrame(['abc', 'cde', 'aec'], columns=['tokens_'])          

In [49]: df['tokens'] = df.tokens_.apply(list)                                  

In [50]: df.drop(['tokens_'], inplace=True, axis='columns')                     

In [51]: df                                                                     
Out[51]: 
      tokens
0  [a, b, c]
1  [c, d, e]
2  [a, e, c]

In [52]: reduce(np.intersect1d, df['tokens'])                                   
Out[52]: array(['c'], dtype='<U1')
```